# ASP.NET MVCScaffolding is very slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, t4scaffolding

We try to use ASP.NET MVC Scaffolding (
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package , http://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/). Great tool, but please any advice why is it so slow? The scaffolding of simple model in an empty project (as described in this tutorial) takes about 15 seconds, which is slow still acceptable, but after we added some scaffolding logic based on our custom metadata attributes, the scaffolding of a model with some one-to-many relationships takes 5 minutes and more, which makes it unusable. Anyways to improve the performance?

Comment: ya it's kind of a joke :-/

Comment: try turn off Windows Defender, it could be cause. (worked for me)

Answer (score -1):

I know it is an old question but maybe this helps someone else. It creates exclusions for Windows Defender for all folders and processes of Visual Studio

```
$userPath = $env:USERPROFILE
$pathExclusions = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$processExclusions = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$pathExclusions.Add('C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add('C:\Windows\assembly') > $null
    
$pathExclusions.Add($userPath + '\.dotnet') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add($userPath + '\.librarymanager') > $null

$pathExclusions.Add($userPath + '\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add($userPath + '\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio Services') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add($userPath + '\AppData\Local\GitCredentialManager') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add($userPath + '\AppData\Local\GitHubVisualStudio') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add($userPath + '\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add($userPath + '\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSApplicationInsights') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add($userPath + '\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add($userPath + '\AppData\Local\Temp\VSFeedbackIntelliCodeLogs') > $null

$pathExclusions.Add($userPath + '\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add($userPath + '\AppData\Roaming\NuGet') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add($userPath + '\AppData\Roaming\Visual Studio Setup') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add($userPath + '\AppData\Roaming\vstelemetry') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add($userPath + '\AppData\Roaming\HeidiSQL') > $null

$pathExclusions.Add('C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add('C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\NetFramework') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add('C:\ProgramData\Microsoft Visual Studio') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add('C:\ProgramData\MySQL') > $null

$pathExclusions.Add('C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add('C:\Program Files\dotnet') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add('C:\Program Files\MySQL') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add('C:\Program Files\IIS') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add('C:\Program Files\IIS Express') > $null

$pathExclusions.Add('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add('C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add('C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS') > $null
$pathExclusions.Add('C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express') > $null

$processExclusions.Add('ServiceHub.SettingsHost.exe') > $null
$processExclusions.Add('ServiceHub.IdentityHost.exe') > $null
$processExclusions.Add('ServiceHub.VSDetouredHost.exe') > $null
$processExclusions.Add('ServiceHub.Host.CLR.x86.exe') > $null
$processExclusions.Add('Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.exe') > $null
$processExclusions.Add('PerfWatson2.exe') > $null
$processExclusions.Add('sqlwriter.exe') > $null

Write-Host "This script will create Windows Defender exclusions for common Visual Studio 2022 folders and processes."
Write-Host ""
$projectsFolder = Read-Host 'What is the path to your Projects folder? (example: c:\source)'

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Adding Path Exclusion: " $projectsFolder
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath $projectsFolder

foreach ($exclusion in $pathExclusions) 
{
    Write-Host "Adding Path Exclusion: " $exclusion
    Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath $exclusion
}

foreach ($exclusion in $processExclusions)
{
    Write-Host "Adding Process Exclusion: " $exclusion
    Add-MpPreference -ExclusionProcess $exclusion
}

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Your Exclusions:"

$prefs = Get-MpPreference
$prefs.ExclusionPath
$prefs.ExclusionProcess

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Enjoy faster build times and coding!"
Write-Host ""
```